# Changing max_load_factor() causing segfault in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

I have `std::unordered_map` which I have initialized with bucket size 100. When I change the `max_load_factor`, code is giving segfault while accessing the `bucket_size()`. I am using g++ as compiler on linux. I want to increase load factor so that elements collide.

1> Why I am getting segfault?
2> What is correct way to set `max_load_factor` for `unordered_map`? as far as I know constructor of `std::unordered_map` does not accept load factor as argument.

Code without setting max_load_factor, gives no problem

```
// unordered_map::bucket_size
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<int, std::string> mymap(10);
  unsigned nbuckets = mymap.bucket_count();
  std::cout << "mymap has " << nbuckets << " buckets:\n";
  std::cout << "mymap load factor " << mymap.max_load_factor() << endl;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<nbuckets; ++i) {
    std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " has " << mymap.bucket_size(i) << " elements.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ g++ -std=c++11  map.cpp  && ./a.out
mymap has 11 buckets:
mymap load factor 1
bucket #0 has 0 elements.
bucket #1 has 0 elements.
bucket #2 has 0 elements.
bucket #3 has 0 elements.
bucket #4 has 0 elements.
bucket #5 has 0 elements.
bucket #6 has 0 elements.
bucket #7 has 0 elements.
bucket #8 has 0 elements.
bucket #9 has 0 elements.
bucket #10 has 0 elements.
```

Now once I introduce the code to change the max_load_factor, I get segfault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<int, std::string> mymap(10);
  unsigned nbuckets = mymap.bucket_count();
  std::cout << "mymap has " << nbuckets << " buckets:\n";
  mymap.max_load_factor(10);
  std::cout << "mymap load factor " << mymap.max_load_factor() << endl;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<nbuckets; ++i) {
    std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " has " << mymap.bucket_size(i) << " elements.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ g++ -std=c++11  map.cpp  && ./a.out
mymap has 11 buckets:
mymap load factor 10
bucket #0 has 0 elements.
bucket #1 has 0 elements.
bucket #2 has 0 elements.
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there's no guarantee whether the container would keep the same bucket count after a change in the `max_load_factor`. If that's the case, you might be iterating over an invalid number of buckets, since `nbuckets` is defined earlier in the code.

Comment: @Itcmelo: you are right. I got exactly same behavior upon testing.  Could you please tell me how to change the max_load_factor without changing bucket count? Or how to provide both bucket count and max_load_factor at the time of the construction of unordered map?

Comment: Set max_load_factor first, and then use `rehash` method to set bucket count. (But it still not guaranteed to produce exactly that bucket count).

Comment: @IlyaPopov: Thanks. rehash seems to be solving my problem. You are right that it is not guaranteed to produce that many buckets, but it will ensure that change is no of buckets does not cause load_factor to be greater than max_load_factor().